# Define global variables in one line Python

Tags: python

Is there a cleaner way to define global variables so that they're all in one line?

Currently I have:

```
SUCCESS = 0                    # Declarations spanning multiple lines
FAIL = 0
TARGET = os.getcwd()
TIMEOUT = 2
MAXDEPTH = 0
ORIGINAL = ''
PATHS = {}

def main():
   aNumber,aString = 1,'hello' # Declarations in one line
   print aString

main()
```

Comment: It's not going to be cleaner.

Comment: you can separate them with `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a separate .py file (with a sensible name) and then

```
from other_file import *
```

Sticking them all on one line is a terrible idea for readability

Answer (score 4):

it's much more readable as separate lines (especially if you line them up):

```
SUCCESS  = 0
FAIL     = 0
TARGET   = os.getcwd()
TIMEOUT  = 2
MAXDEPTH = 0
ORIGINAL = ''
PATHS    = {}
```

But if you really want to do it in a single line, sure!

```
SUCCESS, FAIL, TARGET, TIMEOUT, MAXDEPTH, ORIGINAL, PATHS = 0, 0, os.getcwd(), 2, 0, '', {}
```

Answer (score 2):

But it's not a good idea when you have many variables, it's not user readable, it is used when you have few varibles to initialize.

```
SUCCESS, FAIL, TARGET, TIMEOUT, MAXDEPTH, ORIGINAL, PATHS  = 0, 0, os.getcwd(), 2, 0, '', {}
```